# Washing face towels

Tags: cleaning, home, clothing, laundry, fabric

I have acne prone skin so I use a face towel to dry off my face. When it gets dirty I want to wash it on the highest temperature but I don't want to wash it with anything else that can contaminate it (like underwear etc).

Any hacks to wash face towels with? I do not want to use the washing machine for only one towel.

Comment: If you're concerned about bacterial contamination from the washcloths to other garments, put them in a small pot and boil them on the stove for a few minutes, then wash as normal.

Comment: @jamesqf, I guess OP's fear of contamination is just the other way round.

Comment: @ Stephie: In that case, maybe psychological counseling?

Comment: I've had acne all my life, and I have a few tips. Don't scrub your face; blot it. (This applies to washing it, drying it, or applying lotion.) Don't touch your hands to your face unless they're clean. Wash your hands before you go to sleep too, in case you touch your face at night. If your have a significant other, bacteria from their face can get on yours, so politely wipe off after contact if possible.

Comment: I have the same problem! just use dry wipes! problem solved, and don't forget to change your pillow cover everyday!

Comment: "Don't want to put it with anything else that can contaminate it" - but the other thing is being washed too, and is also an item of clothing that will touch your body, yet its contamination doesn't cause problems where it touches -> perhaps not such a source of contamination after all?

Comment: In addition to things touching your face, consider your diet, detergent that you use, your skin care product ingredients, hair care product ingredients. As mentioned, wash your pillowcase that you alternately rub against your hair/face/hair/face for hours every night. Silk/bamboo pillow cases are less abrasive, too, which is desireable. Good luck.

Answer (score 10):

If you are acne-prone, you should change washcloths and towels very frequently, possibly every day, not just when you feel they are getting "dirty".

My personal "hack" for a similar situation<sup>1</sup> was to invest in a whole load of small washcloths/towels (Ikea has packs of ten for 3€ / £3 / $4 and they can be washed very hot and dumped into the drier, for example.). Alternatively, if you can handle a sewing machine, you could cut up and hem some cheap larger towels. Maybe you even have a few extras around? Then wash them together once you have a full load or your stack is running low.

---

<sup>1</sup> In my case, I used them as "wet wipes" during diaper changes and for all those seemingly endles occasions where a quick wipe was in order. Ten years later, they are still used everyday as washcloths and in a few years, once my children hit the "acne age"... Well, see above.